# Greek chars in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I cannot receive data from Mysql server when I run a PHP query like that:

```
$mysqli->query("utf8_general_ci"); // I have tried "UTF8" - Didn't work
$query =  "SELECT * FROM graf WHERE onoma LIKE 'ΓΕ%' ";
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8_general_ci'");
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
if ($result !=0)
{
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
      echo $row['onoma'];
 }
 }
echo mysqli_error($mysqli); //gives no error
echo mysqli_sqlstate($mysqli); //gives 00000 which means the statement is correct
```

Can somebody help with that? Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following to set up the php content-type:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did that but it did not work. I added that line: 
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'");
before the statement and I got the data without any problem!